# How to restore the backup?

Tags: unbricking

i have a phone MT6589 and i formatted the `/system` and now, the android has dessapeared.

Now the phone is freezed on the boot screen, and i cant turn off the phone because the battery is sticked!

Before all this happens, i have made a backup on the recovery.

Comment: Wait a second. You formatted `/system` (where the OS resides), and no you wonder the device no longer boots? I hope you've created the backup I told you to ;) If you still can boot to recovery, you can restore the Nandroid you made from there (have you tried that?) – otherwise, you can restore from the partitions extracted via FlashTool.

Comment: I cant access the recovery because the buttons dont work, how to access recovery via PC? Adb, fastboot, SP Flash Tool?

Comment: We should chat...

Comment: No idea, I don't even know your device. You can use ADB to tell the device to boot into recovery, but for that the system must be running (which it does not). So you could probably use FlashTool to restore the `/system` partition – provided you backed it up before using FlashTool. Sorry but no, a chat with me won't help, I cannot give further advice.

Comment: i made a backup via recovery, not via flashtool

Comment: Well, you've been warned: remember I told you before to backup the entire device with FlashTool before starting to play with things? FlashTool even works if the MTK device is "dead" (no need to boot it into some special mode, just turn it off). What help is your Nandroid if you cannot boot into recovery? Afraid you'r out of luck then – apart from finding a matching ROM for the device and flashing it via FlashTool. Good luck!